# Duplicated results using fields from relation File Usage: file

Tags: views

I have a content type with a field image and a field file. I made a simple view to get all items of that content. I included in my view a relation ¨File Usage: File¨ to get some data like file size, upload date and uri of file field and for using VBO to download all files.

Now Im getting duplicate results, all data (file size, upload date, vbo) for image field and the same for file field when I just want to get the information for the file field, the image is just a thumbnail. Any ideas of how to get real results over duplicates?

Comment: And checking "reduce duplicates" in the Views advanced settings doesn't help?

Comment: Nop, I already tried but remains duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a File relationship for a specific field, not a File Usage relationship.

In the options for 'Add relationships' select the 'File' filter and you should see an option for each field e.g. 'File: Content using My Field'. Use this and it will give you the same data (file size etc.) but just for files attached to that field.

Comment: Excellent! it works like a charm! thank you very much, its very useful for all my projects. Thank you again!

Comment: I'm having this issue on a view for a content type with a File field and an Image field, I don't see a 'File: Content using My Field' option. When I use the File filter the only option I get is File: Usage

Comment: Should probably mention that you need to add the File:Usage relationship first for the other options to show up and you need to 'require this relationship'. That was the only way I could avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation settings to yes.

1. Go and edit your view
2. In FIELDS or FILTER CRITERIA section, select and apply Aggregation settings for which fields you want to group by or distinct.