# Duplicate node in Views with File Usage

Tags: views, files

I have a content type that has multiple file fields depending to allow the content editor to upload different file types. Only one of the file fields is ever used per content type.

I have a view built that has a relationship to "File Usage: File" to display "File: Size" in the view.

After I modify the file on a node, I start to see duplicates of the node in the view, where the filesize is different but everything else is same. Leading me to believe the File Usage relationship is causing it to be different.

I followed this to no avail, I think the issue is because I have multiple file fields - [Duplicated results using fields from relation File Usage: file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105943/duplicated-results-using-fields-from-relation-file-usage-file)

Does anyone have any other potential solutions?

Edit:
File Usage is definitely the cause here and the fact that I'm utilizing the Size field from File Usage. After a new upload, File Usage creates an additional relationship in the file_usage table between the new file and the node, but also retains the old relationship.

So it all makes sense why there's a duplicate because there is a second unique relationship. Leading me to believe the only way around this is to re-structure that view.

Temporarily we've removed the Size field and the File Usage relationship.